# 표시하였다 not 표시핬어요 or 표시핬습니다

Tags: grammar

그림 1.1에 전압 직렬 귀환 회로에 대하여 개념적인 형태로 표시하였다.

Could anyone explain why 표시하였다 not 표시핬어요 or 표시핬습니다 here? I am sure that there is some grammar I am missing now. Hope you could point it out so I can study it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of `표시핬어요` or `표시핬습니다` are syntactically wrong.
You would like to say `표시했어요` or `표시했습니다`.

### TL;DR

All of these forms actually mean same thing with different moods and tones.

- `표시하였다`.
- `표시했어요`.
- `표시했습니다`.

And the example sentence is speaking in very dry tone like a technical manual, and well matching form is first one. Though there're some syntactic rules, this is more idiomatic rather than syntactic.

### Syntactic Explanation

In this case, `표시` delivers core meanings of `display/show`, and following `-하였다`, `-했어요` and `-했습니다` delivers verb, tense and mood/tones.

These tails can be decomposed into these parts.

```
하 였 다. (decompression of 했다)
하 였 어요. (decompression of 했어요)
하 였 습니다. (decompression of 했습니다)
```

`하` is verb `do`, `였` is tense `did`, and rest delivers tone like in this table.

- `-다`. (dry tone)
- `-어요`. (friendly tone)
- `-습니다`. (formal tone)

Here's how `-하였-` gets compressed.

```
ㅎ ㅏ (ㅇ) ㅕ ㅆ     // `ㅇ` as initial consonant is just a placeholder of no sound. 
ㅎ (ㅏ + ㅕ) ㅆ     // compress two vowels into one.
ㅎ ㅐ ㅆ
```

Some parts can be decomposed further, but I don't know well about them.

### Variations

In this sentence, a few parts are delivering dry-tone.

> 그림 1.1에 전압 직렬 귀환 회로에 **대하여** 개념적인 형태로 **표시하였다**.

If you intend friendly-tone, you can try this. Just compress `-하여` to `-해`, and change ending form. Because decompressed form doesn't match well with friendly-tone.

> 그림 1.1에 전압 직렬 귀환 회로에 **대해** 개념적인 형태로 **표시했어요**.

Some people prefer a bit different form. This is more conversational feeling.

> 그림 1.1에 전압 직렬 귀환 회로에 **대해서** 개념적인 형태로 **표시했어요**.

Or in formal-tone.

> 그림 1.1에 전압 직렬 귀환 회로에 **대해** 개념적인 형태로 **표시했습니다**.

You can use decompressed form in formal-tone because it also matches.

> 그림 1.1에 전압 직렬 귀환 회로에 **대하여** 개념적인 형태로 **표시했습니다**.